# Unable to set null value in NamedQuery of Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am sending `null` value as parameter of JPA NamedQuery and getting Runtime error `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

To accept the `null` value i have programmed `(:publishStatusName is null OR t.publish_status_name=:publishStatusName)` in NamedQuery

Code: Springboot version: `2.1.1`

```
    @NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name="CatalogView.dataTest", query="SELECT t.spid as spid,t.catalog_id as catalogId,t.title_eng as titleEng from {h-schema}catalog_view t WHERE t.locations=:locations AND (:publishStatusName is null OR t.publish_status_name=:publishStatusName)",resultSetMapping="searchResult")
    })
```

Method in my repository

```
 public Set<SearchResult> dataTest(@Param("locations") String locations,@Param("publishStatusName") String publishStatusName);
```

Calling by `myRepository.dataTest(location,null)`

Comment: I tried to simulate error but your code seems to working..Here is a generate query,

`
2018-12-31 23:01:18 --- [   scheduling-1] org.hibernate.SQL : select * from test t where t.test_col =? AND (? is null OR t.test=?)
Hibernate: select * from test  t where t.test_col=? AND (? is null OR t.test=?) 
2018-12-31 23:01:18.114     .sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [123]
2018-12-31 23:01:18.116        : binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
2018-12-31 23:01:18.117       : binding parameter [3] as [VARBINARY] - [null]`

Comment: Can you add generated query?

Comment: could not extract ResultSet means that the query runs but the result cannot be converted to SearchResult. Please post the ResultSetMapping